# Return a set of all keys in a collection of maps

Tags: java, collections

Is there a built in Java method that takes several maps as arguments and returns a set of all keys in these maps?

Something like

```
public static Set<String> getKeys(Map<String, ?> ... arg2){

    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();        
    for (Map<String, ?> map : arg2) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            result.add(key);
        }            
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: None that I know of. If there was, it would be identical to your code ;-)

Comment: No that I'd know of and certainly not in the standard libs. The approach you're using is the way to go although I'd suggest using `keySet()` instead, i.e. `result.addAll( map.keySet() )` - that way you'd not need that inner loop, although it most likely won't make a difference performance wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I know of, no. But let's have some fun with Java 8 streams, shall we?

```
private Set<String> keys(Map<String, ?>... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps).flatMap((map) -> map.keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8 and streams.

```
public static Set<String> getKeys(Map<String, ?> ... arg2){
    return Arrays.stream(arg2)
            .map(Map::keySet)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```